# How can i List all files with .nc (netcdf) in a folder and extract 1 variable out of 10 variable?

Tags: r, list, variables, netcdf, cdo-climate

My task is to get multiple similar **NetCDF** (`.nc`) files from a folder and stack one `a` variable out of 10 variables.

I used:

```
a <- list.files(path=ncpath, pattern = "nc$", full.names = TRUE)
```

This gets me all the files with `.nc` extenstion.

How to proceed for the second task?

I want this variable `a` from these number of files in a folder and stack them.

Comment: Your second task is a bit unclear with what you want, mainly because I dont know what you mean by "stack". It sounds like you are making 10 assignments or that the variable "a" is length 10 and you want to retrieve a single element from it.

Comment: Each NetCDF file has 10 variables. Out of these 10 variables I just one variable, say 'a'. My task is to extract this variable from multiple files so that I have just one file at the end with variable 'a". "Stack, merge, concatenate, append"- make one single raster file by combining multiple raster layers, each containing just one variable "a".

Comment: do those files have the same coordinates? In that case, you might open them with open_mfdataset and save only the variable 'a'

Comment: Yes, they have coordinates...Thanks for your help Justin and Matleo...i managed to extract...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the output in a netcdf file, you might consider doing this task from the command line in linux and using cdo?

```
files=$(ls *.nc)   # you might want to be more selective with your wildcard
# this loop selects the variable from each file and puts into file with the var name at the end
for file in $files ; do 
   cdo selvar,varname $file ${file%???}_varname.nc 
done 
# now merge into one file:
cdo merge *_varname.nc merged_file.nc
```

where you need to obviously replace varname with the name of your variable of choice.

Comment: thanks..cdo does it very well but i am unable to install cdo in cygwin and WLS windows 10 (ubuntu)...thats why trying in R

Comment: Installing a full linux subsystem in windows 10 is now super straightforward, type "install linux in windows 10" into google, for example the first link is here: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-linux-distros-windows-10 then just follow the steps.  Once you have linux installed, just open a window, and type sudo apt-get install cdo, just as you would do on a linux only platform.  Then you can use this script. This is definitely the way to go, cygwin is essentially obsolete on w10...